# Include the document id as a field id in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Heres what i am trying to achieve i want a unique id field for every document in my database and i want that unique id to the same as the document id.

Example:

```
documents:       data:

eBgdTRE123       id:'eBgdTRE123'
                 name:'Jhon Doe'
                 job:'Programmer'
```

i want i databse to have this structure, now i got two ideas to achieve this

1: to use cloud function and have `onCreate` listener and everytime theres a new document grab document and set the id field and update it heres how i am doing it

```
exports.addDocIdToField = 

functions.firestore.document('collectionname/{docID}').onCreate((snap,context) => {
    const id = context.params.docID;
    return admin.firestore().collection('collectionname')
        .doc(id).set({ id: snap.id }, { merge: true })
        .then(() => {
            return null;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return null;
        });
})
```

2: to use the above kind of method on document creation. add a new document as soon as that document is added get the newly added document and update its `id`

both of them work but my question is can i rely on this kind of operation? i mean if the `id` is by any means `undefined` it can cause an error further in the app.

or if there are other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*See JS SDK v9 syntax at the bottom*

There is a simpler way to achieve that, using the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method, as follows (here with the JavaScript SDK v8)

```
var newDocRef = db.collection('collectionname').doc();
newDocRef.set({
                 name:'Jhon Doe',
                 job:'Programmer',
                 id: newDocRef.id
          })
```

As explained in the doc:

> (the `doc()` method) gets a DocumentReference for the document within the collection at the
> specified path. **If no path is specified**, an automatically-generated
> unique ID will be used for the returned DocumentReference.

---

You will find similar methods in the other Client SDKs, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#public-methods_1) for Android and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRCollectionReference#-documentwithautoid) for iOS.

---

**UPDATE FOR JS SDK v9:**

```
import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const newDocRef = doc(collection(db, "collectionname"));
await setDoc(
       newDocRef, 
       {
         name:'Jhon Doe',
         job:'Programmer',
         id: newDocRef.id
       }
   )
```

Comment: Ow so this would create the document and set the id at the same time right?

Comment: The first line generates a `DocumentReference` with an automatically-generated unique ID and the second line just sets the fields of this document and use the automatically-generated unique ID.

Comment: So this will ensure every document is generated with the id field...its perfect thank you

Comment: Firestore v9 version??

Answer (score 0):

the previous method works fine but just for the sake of clarification

what is it  really like

```
const { doc, collection, getFirestore, setDoc, addDoc } = require('firebase/firestore');
let collectionId = "Cars";
let docId;
let firestore = getFirestore();



   async function addDocWithId() {
        let collectionRef = collection(firestore, collectionId)
    
        addDoc(collectionRef, {}).then(res => {
            docId = res.id
            let docRef = doc(firestore, collectionId + "/" + docId)
    
            setDoc(docRef, {
                id: docId,
                car: 'Benz'
            })
        })

    };
```

how it has been clarified

```
const { doc, collection, getFirestore, setDoc, addDoc } = require('firebase/firestore')
let collectionId = "Cars"

let firestore = getFirestore()
async function addDocWithId() {
    let collectionRef = collection(firestore, collectionId)
    let docRef = doc(collectionRef)

    setDoc(docRef, {
        id: docRef.id,
        car: "Volvo"
    })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case if there's anyone who didn't have luck with above provided answers, 
try this -> docref.set({ 'id':docref.ref.id}).
 It worked for me. Below is a usecase of this.

```
create(tutorial: any): any {
    var docref = this.db.collection('invxxx').doc()
    docref.set({ 'id':docref.ref.id, anotherField: 'anotherValue'});
  }
```